IPython notebook run a cell only once during runtime or even lifetime
So I already make it that wrapped into magic cell, it's working fine on Google Colaboratory. But there is package that depends on google library.
Here is the magic cell definition
#@title Register Magic Cell: `run_once`
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from google.colab import output as __output
import hashlib
import time
import os

@register_cell_magic
def run_once(__line: str, __cell: str):
  """
  This custom cell magic command ensures that the notebook cell runs only once during the runtime or even the lifetime.
  If the cell has already been executed before with identical code, it will display the previous output, saving time by avoiding redundant computations.
  Usage: %%run_once <tracker_directory: ./.run_once>
  """
  try:

    # Argument of this magic cell is specifying tracker directory.
    __tracker_dir = __line
    if len(__tracker_dir) == 0:
      __tracker_dir = '.run_once' # Set default if not specified.

    # Create tracker directory.
    if not os.path.exists(__tracker_dir):
      os.makedirs(__tracker_dir)

    # Get cell ID by cell changes with SHA-1 as an identifier.
    __cell_id = hashlib.sha1(__cell.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

    # Check whether __cell_id.html already exists. (Imply the cell already runs)
    if os.path.exists(f'{__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}.html'):
      with open(f'{__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}.html', 'r') as __file_cell_output:
        __html_output = __file_cell_output.read()
      __last_created = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC+00', time.gmtime(os.path.getctime(f'{__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}.html')))
      print(f'This cell ({__cell_id}) already ran before, the last run was ', __last_created, ', displaying history output...\n', sep='')
      display(HTML(__html_output))
      return # Don't do any computations.

    # Actual compute
    get_ipython().run_cell(__cell)

    # After the code has been executed, it will contain some output. Save it!
    __html_output = __output.eval_js('document.getElementById("output-area").innerHTML;')
    with open(f'{__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}.html', 'w') as __file_cell_output:
      __file_cell_output.write(__html_output)

    # Also, save the cell code for archive purposes.
    with open(f'{__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}.cell.py', 'w') as __file_cell_input:
      __file_cell_input.write(__cell)

    # Notify where the history is saved.
    print(f'\nThe cell code and output history pair have been saved at {__tracker_dir}/{__cell_id}')

  except Exception as e:
    print(f"run_once error: {str(e)}")

I want to generalize this magic cell is not only worked on Google Colaboratory but also another environment like Kaggle, or localhost Jupyter Notebook.
Here is the docs to read more how it works: https://github.com/ikhwanperwira/run-once-ipynb
And here is the Colab Notebook: https://github.com/ikhwanperwira/run-once-ipynb/blob/main/run_once_cell.ipynb

It looks like you are using Google Colab only for getting __output. Instead, I think you can use something like with io.capture_output() as captured:. See about io.capture_output() here. Maybe see here and here for more help with it. The latter for how to wrap it in a with context manager.
